# Jquery animate toggle to shift marginTop - demo attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, toggle

I'm having troubles with an open/close tab using jquery. The purpose is for the tab to be clicked to reveal a fullscreen image of a slider sitting below. Technically, the slider itself doesn't change, it just simply alters the marginTop of the panel positioned below it to reveal the fullscreen image of the slider. There is a test link live at: http://www.the3rdobject.com/test-site/index.html - the top tab works perfectly though it is performing a similar function, but cannot get the lower tab to return to it's original position. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To start, simply click on the lower tab 'Show fullscreen image' - this opens up to reveal the slider below. Just need to get it to close.

Any jquery experts, please help! I'm a jquery newb and going out my mind!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Paste the code you've tried inside your question, because the questions here must be self-explained, and the external links only a plus to the question.

Comment: Please paste your code to clarify more... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should work:

```
// gets all the anchor elements inside the elements with a css class 'seefullscreentab'
$(".seefullscreentab a").click(function() {
  // the margin to animate will be 0% if the anchor css class is 'opentab' and -15% if not
  var margin = $(this).hasClass('opentab') ? '0%' : '-15%';
  // animates the element with the css class 'scrollpage-container' to the margin above
  $(".scrollpage-container").animate({ marginTop: margin }, 500);
  // toggle the visibility of the anchors
  // (the current visible anchor turns to hidden, and the hidden one turns to visible)
  $(".seefullscreentab a").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Hey there - thanks for responding... This does work however, it does close the tab, however, it also does something strange to the tab and the toggle of the messages. See the amended edited link... any thoughts? I'm out of my depth with jquery here... have tried a few things but keep getting errors.

Comment: You are, as they say... the man. Any chance you could talk me through it line by line as I don't fully understand the second line. Thanks again - you're a life-saver!

Comment: Thanks again... can you tell me what the '?' does?

Comment: It's only a shorthand for if/else condition: `prop = (condition) ? (true action) : (false action);`

Comment: @Goardo same of `if (condition) { prop = (true action); } else { prop = (false action); }`